# Universal Google Analytics Cross Domain Tracking - Not Tracking Correctly

Tags: analytics

I have a question about setting the "Cross Domain Tracking" at Universal Analytics (analytics.js).

I have a virtual store and use the domain www.dominioA.com.br and checkout is done in another domain www.dominioB.com.br

In Google Analytics Classic (ga.js) used the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-99999999-9']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

In the passage from domain A to domain B that is a FORM / POST, used the following code:

```
_gaq.push (['_linkByPost' document.Form]);
```

Thus the domain B can read the cookies from the domain A and works properly the transition domain.

I'm upgrading to Universal Analytics (analytics.js) and read the instructions given in the article below:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain

In store pages that are in www.dominioA.com.br put the following code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-99999999-9', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['www.dominioB.com.br'] );
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

In store pages that are in www.dominioB.com.br put the following code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-99999999-9', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['www.dominioA.com.br'] );
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Did so the following code is an example on "Tracking multiple domains" page below: 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs#cross-domain

This way does not work, when I change the domain A to domain B, Analytics creates a new session and places like "Traffic Sources" in "Reference" that the new session originated from the domain A.

The domain change occurs in a FORM / POST and want to keep the same session, as he did earlier with the Classic Analytics. Does anyone have any examples of this integration working? Could help me.

I've tried other variations of code, but so far without success.

Thank you.

Alexandre